java POST rest API not working to accept file from AnugularJS
Using angularJS to send post request to Java application however get 405 post not allowed.
Goal is to send file to java server through angularjs post request.
Angular JS code:
var imgMetadata = {author: "a",title: "a",description: "a.",keywords: "a"};

console.log("imgMetadata"+imgMetadata);
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fileMetadata', JSON.stringify(imgMetadata));
fd.append('file', upoadFileField\[0\].files\[0\]);
console.log("Call http");
var REST_BASE_URL = PluginHelper.getPluginRestUrl("apponboarding");
var uploadurl = REST_BASE_URL+ "/iiq/uploadfile";
console.log("File upload url is "+uploadurl);

$http.post(uploadurl, fd, {
  transformRequest: angular.identity,
  headers: {
    "X-XSRF-TOKEN": PluginHelper.getCsrfToken(),
    "Content-Type": undefined
  }
}).then(function successCallback(response) 
{
console.log("In success callback");
var status = response.status;if(status == "200")
{
var isValid = response.data;
console.log("FIleupload function in java "+isValid);
if(isValid == "filecopied"){
    $scope.errorText = "filecopied :";
}
else
{
    $scope.errorText = "Issue in copying";
}
} 
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  console.log("In error callback");
  $scope.errorText = "Error in callback file function";
});

Java Code:
@POST
@Path("/iiq/uploadfile")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    try{
        log.error("file received.");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("filecopied").build();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("Cannot copy!!").build();
    }
}

Error which is get is 405 (Method Not Allowed)
If I remove all the arguments in the public Response uploadFile()
then my function is called and line is printed.
More details on error is:

2024-10-21T12:03:08,357 ERROR http-nio-8080-exec-7 sailpoint.web.SailPointContextRequestFilter:74 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request scope has been already shut down.
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request scope has been already shut down.


I can see "Content-Type": undefined in the request and @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA). Are you sure this will work? Can you try with "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"?

@NikosParaskevopoulos thanks .  tried but no luck , still get 405 error.
